# Include image inside text

Tags: graphics, text

I'm trying to include an image inside a text but it does not work ...

Here is an example of what I would get in latex ...

[image: Here]

Somebody can help me plz?

Thx :)

Comment: Despite, that it is a duplicate, just load package `graphics` or `graphicx` and use command `\includegraphics{example-image-a}` inbetween the words.

Comment: Amazing, thx all and sorry for the duplicate !